# Checking button background and changing

Tags: android, button

How to change the background image of the Button by checking the current image file. Say I want to try the image of sound on/off by checking which image is currently on.

main.xml

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:onClick="onClickSound"
        android:background="@drawable/sound11"
        android:onClick="onClickSound" />
```

main.java

```
public void onClickSound(View view) {
    final Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

    Drawable i = btn1.getBackground();

            /*How to check which image resource is set*/

    btn1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sound00);
}
```

Can any plz help check it. I tried but I can't compare R.drawable.sound00 with "i".

Comment: why do you need to check?

Comment: do you need to swap the drawable of button depending on the button state (on/off)?

Comment: if you have only 2 condition on/off there is no need to check, also checkbox would do better job for that instead of buttom imho

Comment: At any point of time the button image may be sound_on or sound_off. So depending upon the current image, the other image should be updated accordingly. Use case is adding sound button which will toggle on/off

Comment: What do you mean by *I can't compare R.drawable.sound00 with "i".*?

Comment: "i" is Drawable and R.drawable.sound00 is int so I can't compare the both values to check for which image is set. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try having a flag to show what is the last state of the image and update the content according to that. It is a better approach to determine the state on other aspects than the image file itself. Very basically, this can be tried:

```
        boolean isPlayingSound = false; 
        public void onClickSound(View view) {
             //update this variable accordingly
             isPlayingSound = !isPlayingSound
             view.setBackgroundResource(isPlayingSound ? R.drawable.sound11 : R.drawable.sound00);          
        }
```

Comment: `findViewById()` is not needed here, your view is passed as the parameter. `getBackground()` is also redundant, you don't use it. Also, shorter and more readable variant is `btn1.setBackgroundResource(isPlayingSound?R.drawable.sound11:R.drawable.sound00);`

Comment: thanks for pointing out as I've missed view was already passed as a parameter. Updated the answer accordingly

Comment: Thanks Guys!! I tried and it worked. However I have to update the boolean everytime the alternate image is updated to make it work for each click.

Comment: Updating the boolean is also added now in the answer, it just basically switches whenever onClickSound is called